# Sphinx indexer «No error» error

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, full-text-search, sphinx

I have 25GB TSV file and trying to import it with command:

```
D:\sphinx\bin>indexer.exe -c D:\sphinx\sphinx.conf products --rotate
```

It works some time, but then shows error

```
ERROR: index 'products': source 'products_tsv': read error 'No error' (line=4595827, pos=908, docid=4595827).
```

But record at line 4595827 have no problems. 
I have two questions:

1. What's usually causes this problem?
2. Does indexer have any flags for ignoring errors?

Comment: Check the lines before and after, ive seen the number sometimes be a few out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lost a lot of time on checking datafile and found a lot of hidden symbols such as <kbd>SYM</kbd> (`\U001A`), <kbd>NULL</kbd> (`\0000`) and a more of them, which turns Sphinx crazy.
Simply(if «simply» can be said about 25GB file) replaced all <kbd>SYM</kbd> to <kbd>'</kbd> and removed others. 

 We moved forward and faced another issue, but this is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308856/sphinx-large-file-database).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add extra line break after the last line in your `.tsv` data source, so the last line is empty. In my case it helped. Thanks to @stefobark and his repository [stefobark/index_tsv](https://github.com/stefobark/index_tsv)