# ERROR: index 'products': too many string attributes (current index format allows up to 4 GB)

Tags: database, indexing, full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

Got this when tried to index table in database with 25GB of data. 
Sphinx contains index declaration with following fields:

```
sql_field_string    = field_indexer #some keywords
sql_field_string    = product_name
sql_field_string    = description
sql_attr_float      = price
sql_field_string    = product_url
sql_field_string    = image_url
sql_field_string    = sku
sql_attr_uint       = merchant_id
sql_attr_uint       = network_id
```

All of them must be indexed. 
How solve this problem? 
Multiple indexes or distributed indexes are really painful solutions.

Comment: Why you need to store all this fields as attributes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution for your problem for now.

There are several workarounds:

- use distributed index
- make your attrs full text fields (but it makes them "unselectable")
- search in sphinx and query to database for this attrs (2 queries with all disadvantages)

You can choose less painful workaround or switch to another search engine...